# When does gunicorn kill /restart workers?

Tags: gunicorn

I'm correctly investigating an issue with a Flask application which I run with gunicorn on AWS. The problem is that the function seems not to be fully executed. It just runs to a point where it loads a big CSV file into a pandas dataframe and then it seems to break up.

When I run it locally, things work fine. When I run it on AWS, I see

```
[2019-05-23 12:00:25 +0000] [20] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20
```

after a while when the request seems to stop.

Why does gunicorn boot that worker? What happened to the worker before?
(edit: I [start a new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56271540/562769) for the long-running part ... can that be related?)

Comment: Could you explain more about what you mean when you say that it breaks up? Listing more of the gunicorn + flask logs would help. How large is the CSV that you're loading into memory, and what EC2 instance type are you running this on?

Comment: Are you using CloudFront? API Gateway? ELB? Plain EC2? Why do you think it's gunicorn's fault?

Comment: Cloud-Front and API gateway and ECS ... But why should that kill workers?

Comment: @MartinThoma, I would like to inform you, that your `function doLinesIntersect` in [**your answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15001181) is wrong. It gives me `true` by the points like `A {x: 41, y: 111}, B {x: 117, y: 37}, C {x: 43, y: 112}, D {x: 118, y: 39}`, but it should be `false`. Unfortunately I can not write there. I will delete my comment later.